# Gitlab - New project from Gitlab export

Tags: import, gitlab

I'd like to create a new project on Gitlab from an export out of a private Gitlab instance. I exported the repository from the private instance and received a .tar.gz file. According to the official Gitlab.com [documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/settings/import_export.md) I should be able to select "from Gitlab export" when I create a new project but that menu is missing for me.
I found an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/768) on Gitlab but it was closed because the function was added but apparently I am still not able to use it.

Anyone ever used that function? Is there any possibility to move my repo from a private Gitlab to the public one?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [the Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/settings/import_export.html), importing Gitlab exports needs to be administratively enabled first. In your private instances, be sure to upgrade your Gitlab instance to at least 10.3.4 or you may open a [security hole](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/01/16/gitlab-10-dot-3-dot-4-released/).

For the gitlab.com case, I guess it may be disabled because of this issue for now.

EDIT: in fact, now that I look at [it](https://gitlab.com/projects/new), I do see "Gitlab export" listed as the first option.

Comment: Just checked and saw that it’s in fact back now. I think they disabled it temporarily while updating their system 